# Check whether a directory exists or not using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, name-conflict

How to check whether a directory or folder exists or not using javascript or jquery?

Comment: A local directory? Does the user choose a directory that you want to test existence of?

Comment: What kind of a directory - a local directory? A remote directory on a web server?

Comment: Type that exact question into google.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. If Javascript had access to the file system (either client or server), it would be a security hole.

Comment: Not if you're talking about server-side JavaScript like Node.js.  However, browser JavaScript, definitely.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Javascript running in the browser and checking a directory in the user's machine? If so, you'll have a very hard time doing this, as the browser is isolated from the computer's file system for security reasons.

It can't be done.

Good thing too -- if it could be done, there would be any number of malicious hackers using it to find out what software you've got installed, etc. (occasionally the hackers to manage to find a way through the sandbox and do manage to get at the file system, but these holes generally get closed by the browser vendors very quickly)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript cannot access the local filesystem.